# S3 Replication in cross account scenario: Objects replicated in destination account are been deleted when an object in source account is deleted

Tags: xml, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-kms

I am replicated all objects from source account to destination account. When an object in source account is deleted , objects in destination accounts are deleted.Even though I encrypted the destination bucket. Is there any required parameter to add to this replication format??

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGhgo.png)

Comment: Try turning on versioning. If I remember correctly, the "delete marker" of versioned objects has to be removed before the items can be deleted. Maybe this will prevent deletes at the target, however, replication may take this into account.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 senarios here:

1. It looks like you may have `Delete Marker Replication` turned on. This setting replicates delete markers from the source bucket into the target bucket. It can be turned off. If you set up your replication via the aws console then navigate to your source bucket in the aws console and select the `Management` tab where you can then select your `Replication rule`. If you scroll down to `Additional Replication Options` you will see the checkbox. Just uncheck it and save. The [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/replication-what-is-isnot-replicated.html) give a good summary on what happens to a delete action in terms or replication.
2. You used the CLI or SDK and need to edit the replication configuration. In your `Rules` array, after the `Destination` object add another object like this as per the [docs](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/managing-delete-marker-replication-in-amazon-s3/):

   ```
    "DeleteMarkerReplication": {
        "Status": "Disabled"
    },
   ```

Keep versioning turned on as it best practice, it allows you to [to preserve, retrieve, and restore every version of every object stored in your buckets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/Versioning.html).